# How to insert link's domain name in plain text after a hyperlink?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

Is there a way to automatically insert link's domain name after that link? I want to see this:

`A link to youtube video [youtube.com]`

I'd prefer to use HTML and CSS only, but I guess that's not possible. The idea was using this code:

```
  a:after {
    content: " [" attr(href) "]";
  }
```

But that of course displays the whole URL:

`A link to youtube video [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asdfghi00]`

And I consider that too long and unnecessary. I use Wordpress (maybe there's just a plugin for doing this and I just haven't seen it). It links jQuery, so a jquery script is probably acceptable. Alternatively I could use PHP and hack it into Wordpress.

What solution do you consider the best? PHP or Javascript? Will I benefit from using jQuery (well, it's loaded anyway)? If possible, could you write this snippet for me? Thanks.

Comment: Well since its Wordpress there is a variable for the links , find the variable trim off what you don't want and append it to links possibly

Answer (score 2):

If you can afford putting another attribute on your links, you can do that.

[Here's an example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BgKvj)

In your markup, add a `data-` attribute:

```
<a href="youtube.com/foo" data-href-domain="youtube.com">a link to youtube video</a>
```

And reference it using generated content as you tried:

```
a:after {
 content: " [" attr(data-href-domain) "]";
}
```

Comment: I thought of using custom attribute, but the problem is the fact that setting custom attributes in Wordpress is quite hard. I'd also have a redundant information that'd be necessary to update and think of when I change the link.

Comment: I don't know how you generate those links, but you definitely use a function there.

Comment: Wordpress uses TinyMCE to create posts. It is possible to edit HTML directly, but that's not convenient for ordinary users.

Answer (score 1):

This question is old, but here is how you can do it with jQuery:

```
$('a').each(function () {
    this.hostname && $(this).after(' ['+this.hostname+']');
});
```

Edit: You can try it out here on stackoverflow by pasting it right into the console

Answer (score 0):

When I think of it, one of possible solutions would be to create a custom shortcode (with the help of plugin [Shortcoder](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/shortcoder/) or similar). That would allow me to make both classic links and links with the address shown quite comfortly. I'd use syntax for shortcoder similar to this:

```
<a href="http%%s%%://%%domain%%/%%link%%">%%text%%</a> [%%domain%%]
```

Using it - `Lorem Ipsum [sc:extlink s="s" domain="youtube.com" link="watch?v=asd" text="link" ] Dolor Dot.` translates to:

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum <!-- Start Shortcoder content --><a href="https://youtube.com/watch?v=asd">link</a> [youtube.com]<!-- End Shortcoder content --> Dolor Dot.</p>
```

or

```
<a class="with-note" href="http%%s%%://%%domain%%/%%link-tail%%" data-href-domain="%%domain%%">%%text%%</a>
```

with the latter using CSS in the way Alessandro [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14489079/1306158). But still it's not that nice and confortable as it probably should be. Just an option if noone can come with something better.